# How to fetch data/content from database for my custom localhost URL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, content-management-system

1. I have three field:-

   `Title, Content & Url (url=localhost/form.php)`.

   Insert the data (`Title=About us, Content = xyz and Url=/aboutus`) into `MySql DB`.
2. Now if I put url like "`localhost/aboutus`" , it will show the Title
   and Content for this particular url.

E.g. :-

```
localhost/aboutus
Tile: About us
Content: xyz
```

Comment: please explain what code is running on localhost, what it's supposed to be doing, how it interacts with the database, etc.

Comment: Hi jwriteclub, I'm using PHP for this. I'm about to insert and select the data from the database. After inserting the data into DB, I want to get Title and Content by using url (like, localhost/aboutus)

Comment: This questions has to be corrected, I can't tell what the issue is, there is no clear question or issue described. Using PHP is not sufficient information. Also there is a wordpress and a cms tag added that I can't find any reference to in the question.

Comment: It is just like wordpress, so when we create a post/page and it give us a auto generated permalink , like '' http://localhost/wordpress/new-media/". Here in this context I'm adding this "new-media" parameter into my database and want to use this "new-media" parameter to open the same page in a new tab if I enter the same link and it show me other data like , Title and Content. Exactly as Wordpress but on my localhost. Thanks

Comment: jnhghy - Alexandru Jantea , I know somehow that the main page needs to read the parameter and then look up in the database for that parameter and return the proper permalink value but I can't figure all of this out.

Answer (score 0):

did u created the particular URLs previously or trying to generate by submitting the form ?

Comment: It is just like wordpress, so when we create a post/page and it give us a auto generated permalink , like '' http://localhost/wordpress/new-media/". Here in this context I'm adding this "new-media" parameter into my database and want to use this "new-media" parameter to open the same page in a new tab if I enter the same link and it show me other data like , Title and Content. Exactly as Wordpress but on my localhost. Thanks

Comment: I know somehow that the main page needs to read the parameter and then look up in the database for that parameter and return the proper permalink value but I can't figure all of this out.